# externally access the application using hostname/subdomain in ingress resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kube-dns

Need to access the application from external using Ingress **hostname/sub-domain** for the application that is specified in the below code. **eg.** test-app.dev-cluster-poc.company.domain.

cat app-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test-app.dev-cluster-poc.company.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: appsvc1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1
      - backend:
          serviceName: appsvc2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app2
```

While troubleshooting using steps in the [url](https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-troubleshooting-ingress-and-services-traffic-flows-547ea867b120), I found that there is no ADDRESS in the "kubectl get ingress" output. expecting an ip address like below.

[image]

but, I am seeing like below, 3rd column is empty.
[image]

what are the necessary configuration required to externally access the application like registering the hostname(test-app.dev-cluster-poc.company.domain) or adding A-record or running any dns service in the kubernetes cluster.

what is causing the ADDRESS column empty in "kubectl get ingress" command.

[EDIT]

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: appsvc1
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app1
```

Nginx controller service like below.

```
cat nginx-ingress-controller-service.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30000
      name: http
    - port: 18080
      nodePort: 32000
      name: http-mgmt
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress-lb
```

Comment: Where is your cluster running? the answer is very different depending on the cloud provider

Comment: @paltaa - it's running in a VMware pks. I can get the dns name added, but would like to know what other config is required to make this work from end-to-end. Also, why there is no Address for my ingress, any clue?

Comment: I think it depends on what kind of `serviceType` your service `appsvc1` &  `appsvc2` are defined as. If they're defined as `LoadBalancer` and your provider can provide extra IP-addresses, the address field should be populated with that IP (I.e every ingress get a unique IP). If they're defined as `ClusterIP` or `NodePort` the `ADDRESS` field will be empty and the kube proxy IP will be used. Although I could be wrong...

Comment: As mentioned by community id depends on the cloud provider implementation, you mentioned that you are using VMware pks, maybe loadbalancer should be provisioned during cluster creation [Load Balancers in PKS](https://docs.pivotal.io/pks/1-3/about-lb.html) [Kubernetes and VMware Enterprise PKS Networking](https://blogs.vmware.com/networkvirtualization/2019/06/kubernetes-and-vmware-enterprise-pks-networking-security-operations-with-nsx-t-data-center.html/). You can use commands `kubectl describe ingress ..` to see more from the ingress resource  `kubectl get svc` type Loadbalanacer

Comment: @t3ng1l - the service does not have any explicit type defined. so it is of type ClusterIP. The provider can add the dns name, but I believe DNS mapping is IP to domain.name and domain.name to IP. so I believe I need an IP for Ingress. otherwise how the dns will resolve and redirect traffic to ingress.

Comment: Your service needs to be of type LoadBalancer or NodePort, otherwise, they are not reachable from outside the cluster so no routing could be made. Try changing it to LoadBalancer.

Comment: @paltaa - changing the service type to LoadBalancer and recreating the ingress populated with IP address. but seeing a msg "<html><p>No server is available to handle this request.</p></html>" when hitting the url http://INGRESS_IP_ADDRESS/app1

Answer (score 0):

1.you can deploy an ingress deployment

2.expose your ingress deployment through port 80

```
kubectl expose deploy your-deployment-name --port 80
```

[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose)

3.you can add ingressClassName in your deploy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

[ingress configuration sample](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/)